# Downloadable templates and styles for Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, download, themes, styles, microsoft-word-2010

Where can I find downloadable templates and styles for Word 2010?

I'm not a designer, but would like to find pre-packaged sets of fonts, colors and indenting that is more appealing that what is built in.

Answer (score 9):

> In Word 2010, installing additional templates is quite easy, you can find lots of free and attractive looking templates from Office.com. Hit the Template name from the list displayed under the Office.com Templates section, and click the Download button located in the left side, under the preview image of the template.

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/microsoft-word-2010-templates/

More templates here
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/templates-partners-FX010242583.aspx

.

Styles can be modified in Word 2010

http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/styles/modifyastyle.html

.

Answer (score 0):

See the following links for help:

- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/CL101829555.aspx
- http://www.templatemagician.com/website-templates.html

Comment: Tried to vote down as I dont see what advertising website-templates has to do with Word 2010 Templates and Styles, but dont have enough rep yet.

Comment: They're places to get templates, which is what the OP asked for.